# Search FlagRequest for single or multiple text combinations

Tags: vba, outlook

In my inbox there are emails where the sender communicates either single or multiple seminars or event codes.

For example, AI-G167 and/or HR-T245. I flag those emails with category and flag request and this helps me add functionality in my code.

My filter only works when FlagRequest has a single event code and fails when I mark FlagRequest with a delimited value, e.g "AI-G167, HR-T245".

```
Category_Filter = "[Categories] = 'Seminars' And [FlagRequest] = " & EventCode
```

Is there any way, my filter could work in this scenario? It means that email would serve my purpose even if there are two different events to be held on a single day at different times.

Comment: I suggest this is not enough information. Some code may be helpful. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Restrict` does not support `like` for `.FlagRequest` there is `InStr`.

```
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub FlagRequest_multiple_values()
    
    Dim oItems As Items
    Dim oItemsRes As Items
        
    Dim Category_Filter As String
    Dim Category_Flag_Filter As String
    
    Dim EventCode As String
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim resItemsCount As Long
    Dim matchCount As Long
    
    Set oItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("FlagRequestTest").Items
    
    EventCode = "AI-G167"
    'EventCode = "HR-T245"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "EventCode......: " & EventCode
    
    ' with single quotes added to variable
    Category_Flag_Filter = _
      "[Categories] = 'Seminars' And [FlagRequest] = " & "'" & EventCode & "'"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Category_Flag_Filter......: " & Category_Flag_Filter
    
    Set oItemsRes = oItems.Restrict(Category_Flag_Filter)
    Debug.Print "Category_Flag_Filter count: " & oItemsRes.Count
    
    Category_Filter = "[Categories] = 'Seminars'"
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Category_Filter......: " & Category_Filter

    Set oItemsRes = oItems.Restrict(Category_Filter)
    Debug.Print "Category_Filter count: " & oItemsRes.Count
    
    If oItemsRes.Count > 0 Then
        
        resItemsCount = oItemsRes.Count
        
        For i = 1 To resItemsCount
            With oItemsRes(i)
            
                Debug.Print i & " Subject......: " & .Subject
                Debug.Print "    FlagRequest: " & .FlagRequest

                If InStr(.FlagRequest, EventCode) > 0 Then
                    matchCount = matchCount + 1
                Else
                    Debug.Print "    *** No match ***"
                End If
                
            End With
        Next
        
    End If
    
    Debug.Print matchCount & " matches of " & resItemsCount
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was so much helpful. At the back of my head, I kept thinking of using instr function but I had no idea how to incorporate this with a Category filter or FlagRequest. You precisely addressed the issue.

Comment: Hi Niton, I would like to know if there could be a way to avoid the looping process through all those category wise filtered emails. If not, then I am fine with existing code.

Comment: Restrict is the way to avoid looping. You could reduce the number of loops if there are seminars without events `Category_Flag_Filter = "[Categories] = 'Seminars' And [FlagRequest] <> """""`.